# Evaluation of Delegated Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm interested in knowing the order of constructor evaluation when using delegation.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Number(){
    length = 100;
    values = new int[length];
};
Number(int len) : Number(){
    length = len;
}
```

Note that they both modify length, but only one applies that length to a new array. This code works.

My question: 
    Why does it work?
    Do the constructors only apply the code that is non-redundant?
    Or maybe, in this situation, the default constructor is called before the code in the non-default constructor?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Tip: Try to avoid using C-style arrays and `new[]`. Instead use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and other Standard Library containers. These make memory management significantly easier and can be passed by reference with information on size intrinsically included.

Comment: Your delegated constructor happens before the constructor's body, as does anything else in the member initializer list. `values` points to an array of 100 elements every time, regardless of `len`. Please share the rest of your code that you used to determine the behavior you are claiming.

Comment: *that's what delegation is for!* – Nope.

Comment: It will only work if you stay in bounds of the memory you have allocated. If you happen to allocate more memory than needed, all you do is waste resources but it won't harm anything else (unless you allocate way to much and run into the limits of your system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructors don't know how to skip anything unless you tell them to, but in the case of constructor delegation that kind of communication will be hard because the values could be uninitialized, or they could be populated and it's really not easy to tell the difference.

Instead structure it this way:

```
Number() : length(100) {
  allocateValues();
};

Number(int len) : length(len) {
  allocateValues();
}

void allocateValues() {
  values = new int[length];
}
```

This is really poor form though since `std::vector` and friends can help you out. Consider something like this using [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

```
Number() {
  values.insert(values.begin(), len, 100);
}

Number(int len) {
  values.insert(values.begin(), len, 0);
}
```